# How do I use Harmony to repeatedly replace an arbitrary method?

Tags: c#, cil

I need to replace a method with a call to a method with the same signature so that I can essentially replace the original method with a new method. Currently, I have the code below, which works, but when I try to patch the method again, it simply does nothing. I'm not sure if that's because Harmony doesn't like when I try to transpile it twice, or something else, either way it prevents me from repeatedly redirecting the original method.

```cs
// this is factored out of Transpiler() because yield return reasons
private static IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> TranspilerIterator(IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> instructions,
    MethodBase original) {
    var name = original.Name;
    var par = original.GetParameters();
    var method = newGuiType.GetMethod(name, (BindingFlags) FLAGS);
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} == null == {method == null}");

    if ((method.CallingConvention & CallingConventions.HasThis) != 0)
        yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

    for (var i = 0; i < par.Length; i++)
        yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, par[i].Position + 1);

    yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Call, method);
    yield return new CodeInstruction(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

which is called by this:

```cs
private void DoPatches() {
    Logger.Debug("Performing patches.");

    var methods = oldGuiType.GetMethods((BindingFlags) FLAGS);
    
    var t = this.GetType().GetMethod("Transpiler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    for (var i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++) {
        var name = methods[i].Name;
        Logger.Debug($"Transpiling {name}");
        harmony.Patch(methods[i], transpiler: new HarmonyMethod(t));
    }
}
```

I can't use a prefix because I need to know the signature to get the args in a prefix, and I don't know the signature.

I know there are other libraries to make essentially this, but the game I'm modding ships with Harmony so I don't have to ship a whole lib with my very small mod.

Comment: Have you tried using ILSpy or a similar tool to get the method signature, then you could use a prefix?

Comment: That won't work because the signature is unknown at compile time.

Comment: The Harmony doc. [Transpiler Patching](https://harmony.pardeike.net/articles/patching-transpiler.html#transpiler) says, _"**A transpiler is executed only once before the original is run**. It can therefore not have access to any runtime state. Harmony will run it once when you patch the method and again every time someone else adds a transpiler for the same methods."_ So it seems it may execute only the first time to splice the code. Another thing, I noticed your loop to work with `CodeInstruction` is outside your transpiler, in the doc's example it's inside the transpiler.

Comment: It's called to patch multiple methods not working with `CodeInstruction`.

Answer (score 1):

For every change to an original method (like adding or removing a transpiler) Harmony will recalculate the replacement method by doing this (in pseudo code):

```
original_IL -> transpiler1 -> transpiler2 -> ... -> transpiler_n -> replacement_IL
```

where transpiler 1..n are all active transpilers. It then build the replacement by (roughly) structuring it like this:

```
// Note: the following is very simplified and only used to illustrate
// the difference between prefix/postfix and a transpiler.

REPLACEMENT()
{
   if (Prefix_1() == false) return
   // ...
   if (Prefix_n() == false) return

   // replacement_IL_here

   Postfix_1()
   // ...
   Postfix_n()
}
```

Internally, Harmony has to therefore keep track of all patches and since those can be from different Assemblies it would need to serialize/deserialize state - which is in principle impossible if you have arbitrary state. Therefore, it only stores the simplest key for each patch possible: its `MethodInfo` which must be a static method.

As a result you cannot apply the same patch multiple times. It makes little sense since you could easily put all your code into one patch anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For this application, ie updating a method to a newer method with an identical signature, `Memory.DetourMethod(MethodBase original, MethodBase replacement)` did what I needed.

```cs
// assuming newType is just a newer version of oldType
var newMethod = newType.getMethod("SomeMethod");
var oldMethod = oldType.getMethod("SomeMethod");
Memory.DetourMethod(oldMethod, newMethod);
```

This code effectively replaces the old method with the new method. The way it actually works is [a bit more complicated](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony/blob/381b72c48a9929c55e3469d2bd50b3176a6d5f89/Harmony/Internal/Memory.cs#L34).